# PHPWord Vertical Alignment of text in a cell

Tags: phpword

I am trying to align text veritcally in a cell in PHPWord.

```
$cellHCentered = array('alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER);
```

Works for horizontal alignment but I can't find the solution for vertical, Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The solution may not be perfect!

Check spaceAfter & spaceBefore on the 3rd line of the below code - Adds space before and after the text. I assigned 250. You can provide your own value.

```
$table = $section->addTable(['borderSize' => 6]);
$table->addRow(); 
$table->addCell(2000)->addText("Text in the Cell",['name'=>'Times New Roman','size' => 12],['spaceAfter' => 250,'spaceBefore' => 250]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        $cell = $table->addCell(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(1.25), [
            'valign' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\VerticalJc::BOTTOM
        ]);
        $cell->addText('Text', null, [
            'spaceBefore' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0),
            'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0),
            'align' => 'end'
        ]);
```

Allthough, the manual actual says to use this:

```
'valign' => 'bottom'
```

BTW, these function also:

```
'vAlign' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\VerticalJc::BOTTOM

'vAlign' => 'bottom'
```

So I conclude there is some overlap between the Section and Cell vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Cell, pass ['valign' => 'center'] as style parameter:

```
$table->addCell($someWidth, ['valign' => 'center'])->addText(...);
```